# Does span which is subpsace ensures linearly independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $b_1...b_p$ span a subspace $W$, does it ensure $b_1...b_p$ is a linearly independent set?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Take any spanning set, and add another element of $W$ to the set. Then it cannot possibly be linearly independent, but is still spanning.

Answer (score 1):

No. Given any vectors that span a subspace, their linear independence is equivalent to the dimension of $W$ being equal to $p$.